# Get facebook friends from open graph user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access a users friends, but I can't seem to figure out how I would go about doing that. There is no explicit method to access the friends list, so I figured it may be a property, but that does not seem to work. I am trying to go through the docs and have found some helpful information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/#step3) but I still can't figure this out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. If you use a request, you can find a list of the users friends using the current session. The code I use is

```
Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(Session.getOpenSession(), new GraphUserListCallback() {

@Override
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
    // TODO 

}
});
```

Comment: How can we obtain the friends email addresses, or phone numbers using this method. `GraphUser` does not have getter method for `getEmail` or `getPhoneNumber` etc...